# Using AmazonSQS sendMessage over multiple threads causes it to run slower

Tags: java, multithreading, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-sqs

I've got an app that sends simple SQS messages to multiple queues. Previously, this sending happened serially, but now that we've got more queues we need to send to, I decided to parallelize it by doing all the sending in a thread pool (up to 10 threads).

However, I've noticed that sqs.sendMessage latency seems to increase when I throw more threads at the job!

I've created a sample program below to reproduce the problem (Note that `numIterations` is just to get more data, and this is just a simplified version of the code for demo purposes).

Running on EC2 instance in the same region and using 7 queues, I'm typically getting average results around 12-15ms with 1 thread, and 21-25ms with 7 threads - nearly double the latency!

Even running from my laptop remotely (when creating this demo), I'm getting average latency of ~90ms with 1 thread and ~120ms with 7 threads.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    AWSCredentialsProvider creds = new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(new BasicAWSCredentials(A, B));
    final int numThreads = 7;
    final int numQueues = 7;
    final int numIterations = 100;
    final long sleepMs = 10000;

    AmazonSQSClient sqs = new AmazonSQSClient(creds);
    List<String> queueUrls = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i=0; i<numQueues; i++) {
        queueUrls.add(sqs.getQueueUrl("testThreading-" + i).getQueueUrl());    
    }

    Queue<Long> resultQueue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>(); 
    sqs.addRequestHandler(new MyRequestHandler(resultQueue));

    runIterations(sqs, queueUrls, numThreads, numIterations, sleepMs);
    System.out.println("Average: " + resultQueue.stream().mapToLong(Long::longValue).average().getAsDouble());
    System.exit(0);
}

private static void runIterations(AmazonSQS sqs, List<String> queueUrls, int threadPoolSize, int numIterations, long sleepMs) throws Exception {
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadPoolSize);
    List<Future<?>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i=0; i<numIterations; i++) {
        for (String queueUrl : queueUrls) {
            final String message = String.valueOf(i);
            futures.add(executor.submit(() -> sendMessage(sqs, queueUrl, message)));
        }
        Thread.sleep(sleepMs);
    }

    for (Future<?> f : futures) {
        f.get();
    }

}

private static void sendMessage(AmazonSQS sqs, String queueUrl, String messageBody) {
    final SendMessageRequest request = new SendMessageRequest()
            .withQueueUrl(queueUrl)
            .withMessageBody(messageBody);
    sqs.sendMessage(request);
}

// Use RequestHandler2 to get accurate timing metrics
private static class MyRequestHandler extends RequestHandler2 {
    private final Queue<Long> resultQueue;
    public MyRequestHandler(Queue<Long> resultQueue) {
        this.resultQueue = resultQueue;
    }

    public void afterResponse(Request<?> request, Response<?> response) {
        TimingInfo timingInfo = request.getAWSRequestMetrics().getTimingInfo();
        Long start = timingInfo.getStartEpochTimeMilliIfKnown();
        Long end = timingInfo.getEndEpochTimeMilliIfKnown();
        if (start != null && end != null) {
            long elapsed = end-start;
            resultQueue.add(elapsed);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm sure this is some weird client configuration issue, but the default ClientConfiguration should be able to handle 50 concurrent connections.

Any suggestions?

**Update**: It's looking like the key to this problem is something I left out of the original simplified version - there is a delay between batches of messages being sent (relating to doing processing). The latency issue isn't there if the delay is ~2s, but it *is* an issue when the delay between batches is ~10s.  I've tried different values for `ClientConfiguration.validateAfterInactivityMillis` with no effect.

Comment: How's your CPU utilization?  Relatively speaking, negotiating TLS and signing the API requests are both somewhat CPU intensive.

Comment: CPU is super low - currently running on m4.large instances and CPU is barely cracking 5% at max.

Comment: It's not a FIFO queue, with a 300 trx/sec limit, is it?  Multiple queues, you said, so probably not, but...

Comment: Nope, just a regular queue. I'm not seeing any throttling/retries either (I'm collecting metrics on that in my production service that I left out to simplify the sample above)

Comment: Updated - delay between batches of messages seems to be key to this issue. Hopefully this will help any potential answerers...

Comment: When you say "delay between batches," you're talking about the amount of time that elapses between each time you call sendMessage?  And the "latency" you're talking about how refers to how long it takes to call sendMessage?  Not throughput latency (enqueue -> dequeue) but just time to send?

Comment: not delay between "each" call to sendMessage, but between each message being sent to multiple queues. For example: message 1 gets sent to 7 queues, then delay, then message 2 send to 7 queues, then delay. By latency, I'm referring strictly to the timing for sendMessage (as provided by `request.getAWSRequestMetrics().getTimingInfo()` in the code above.

Comment: Almost unrelated, but... you do know that you can send a message to multiple queues at the same time by using SNS > SQS fan-out, right?  Anyway... the increased time after a longer wait is almost certainly related to an HTTP keepalive timer.  SQS (or any web service) won't allow you to keep a kept-alive connection for more than a few seconds, typically.  I'd look at the network level with a packet sniffer for an explanation of the behavior change.

Comment: Yeah I know about the SNS thing :) good info to have & share in general, and I appreciate your insights.  In my case, however, SNS just adds another service dependency to manage (again,
 code above is a simplified demo), and I've actually found it slower on average than doing it like this.

Comment: Looking likely that this is not an SDK issue but SQS service issue - AWS RequestMetrics HttpClientReceiveResponseTime (amount of time it takes after sending the request to receive the response) is nearly perfectly correlated in all of my test scenarios.